# Average in Adjusted cosine Similarity

Tags: cosine-similarity

what is the denominator in average rating of a user in Adjusted cosine similarity? (Item Based Collaborative Filtering)

Is it number all Items in system?? Or Just number of rated items by user??

and

is there a function in MatLab for Adjusted Cosine?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Is it number all Items in system?? Or Just number of rated items by
> user??
>
> Answer 1: Neither

If you see this formula:

[image: Adjusted Cosine]

in the denominator you need to calculate the *rooted sum* for each Rating of user *u* for item *i* minus the average rating of this User (*mean rating*) and this subtraction is squared then it is the same thing for item j which you have to multiply together.

> Question 2: is there a function in MatLab for Adjusted Cosine?
>
> Answer 2: By default no. But it should be relatively easy to write it your self given that you have the formula.